# Google Map Place Marker On DOM Event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Currently what I have is an initialized Google Map with a DOM listener that is triggered when my form button is clicked. My function is called when the event occurs, however, the marker is not being placed on the map, despite hardcoding a test location to do so. Here's some of my code...

```
// script for calculating current geolocation
var map, infoWindow, marker, searchBtn;
var myCenter= {lat: 48.752, lng: -122.479};

function initMap() {
    var mapDiv = document.getElementById('map');
    searchBtn = document.getElementById('search-btn');
    map = new google.maps.Map(mapDiv, {
        center: myCenter,
        zoom: 12,
        mapTypeContol: true,
        mapTypeControlOptions: {
            style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.HORIZONTAL_BAR,
            position: google.maps.ControlPosition.BOTTOM_CENTER
        }
    });

    infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(searchBtn, 'click', function() {
        geocode_input();
    });
}

/* Used for retrieving address data (i.e. lat, lng, etc.) from Google Map API */
    function geocode_input() {
        console.log("geocode running...");
        var x = document.getElementById("address_form");
        var old = x.elements[0].value;
        var replaced = old.replace(/\s/g, '+');
        var request = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=" + replaced + "&key=KEY";
        var pos = {};
        $.ajax({
            url : 'http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json',
            type : 'GET',
            data : {
                address : replaced,
                sensor : false
            },
            async : false,
            success : function(result) {
                console.log("yay");
                console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
                pos.lat = result.results[0].geometry.location.lat;
                pos.lng = result.results[0].geometry.location.lng;
                pos.dist = 10;
                // logging for testing
                console.log(JSON.stringify(pos));
                // clinicData = clinicRequest(pos, clinicCallback); FIXME: uncomment
                clinicCallback(pos);
            }
        });
        return pos;
    }

var clinicCallback = function displayClinics(clinicData) {
        console.log("displaying clinic data...");
        var testLoc = {lat: 48.746, lng: -122.482};
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position:testLoc,
            map: map
        });

        marker.addListener('click', function() {
            infoWindow.open(map, marker);
        });
    }
```

View:

```
<div class="searchForm">
        <form id="address_form">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="address" placeholder="Enter street address">
            </div>
            <div class="input-group-btn">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" id="search-btn">
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i>
                </button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>

    <!-- Sidebar: location, filters -->
    <!-- for location: split on spaces, turn request into https to geocoding api, send our server the appropriate lat/long -->

    <!-- jQuery first, then Tether, then Bootstrap JS. -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <!-- <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/addrSearch.js') }}"></script> -->
    <!-- Google Map "code" -->
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=KEY&callback=initMap"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/map.js') }}"></script>
```

The code gets all the way to the point of logging "displaying clinic data..." and that is it. No marker being created.

Any idea why this might be happening?

Thank you.

Comment: you want a marker to be added on map load?

Comment: After map load.

Comment: console reads "displaying clinic data..." yeah?

Comment: @John That is correct.

Comment: Marker's `position` property must be of `google.maps.LatLng()` class, not plain object. Therefore `var testLoc = new google.maps.LatLng({lat: 48.746, lng: -122.482});`.

Comment: Similarly, in order to use the geocoding service, you need to create a `new google.maps.Geocoder()` object, then call its `.geocode()` method. Follow the example [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-simple).

Comment: @Roamer-1888 Thank you. That worked.